# Phaser: Attach Touch Event on Sprite

Tags: touch, phaser-framework

I'am new to phaser and right now Im using phaser v.2.0.7. What I want to do is to make a sprite handle a touch event.

How can I attach `onTap` to a sprite object?

I know that touch event would be possible with `sprite_obj.events.onInputDown`, but still I used `onInputUp` either because when there is a popup/modal(alert) fired after the `onInputDown`, you need to click twice after that to make the event listener work again. [(My personal workaround for this issue is using inInputUp.)](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/4355-click-on-an-image-not-working/)

Another thing that I've tried is to add `onTap` on my canvas object, `canvas.input.onTap.add` which I think does not fit to attain my goal. Yes, it can now handle touch events but the problem is I want to limit the touch event only to the sprite image on the canvas and not the whole canvas.

Can someone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You first need to enable the Sprite for input:

`sprite.inputEnabled = true;`

You can then listen to any of the events the Sprite dispatches when it's involved in input, such as:

```
sprite.events.onInputDown.add(onDown, this);

...

function onDown(sprite, pointer) {
 // do something wonderful here
}
```

The callback is sent 2 parameters: the Sprite and the Pointer that caused the input event (as in a multi-input system this can vary often)

The Pointer has lots of properties you can access, such as the time it was placed down, movement history, etc. See the [Pointer docs](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Pointer.html) for details.

The Sprite has lots of events, but these are the Input related ones (this is lifted direct from the Phaser source code):

```
/**
* @property {Phaser.Signal} onInputOver - This signal is dispatched if the parent is inputEnabled and receives an over event from a Pointer.
* @default null
*/
this.onInputOver = null;

/**
* @property {Phaser.Signal} onInputOut - This signal is dispatched if the parent is inputEnabled and receives an out event from a Pointer.
* @default null
*/
this.onInputOut = null;

/**
* @property {Phaser.Signal} onInputDown - This signal is dispatched if the parent is inputEnabled and receives a down event from a Pointer.
* @default null
*/
this.onInputDown = null;

/**
* @property {Phaser.Signal} onInputUp - This signal is dispatched if the parent is inputEnabled and receives an up event from a Pointer.
* @default null
*/
this.onInputUp = null;

/**
* @property {Phaser.Signal} onDragStart - This signal is dispatched if the parent is inputEnabled and receives a drag start event from a Pointer.
* @default null
*/
this.onDragStart = null;

/**
* @property {Phaser.Signal} onDragStop - This signal is dispatched if the parent is inputEnabled and receives a drag stop event from a Pointer.
* @default null
*/
this.onDragStop = null;
```

Comment: thanks dude. but i cannot use onInputDown :( why?  because it has issue with popups like alert() and bootstrap modal described in the issue here: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/4355-click-on-an-image-not-working/

Comment: I don't really understand the relevance of the issue in that URL to what you said you were trying to do. onInputDown isn't a DOM event, it's a Signal. If you need to capture DOM events you need to capture them on DOM elements, they can't be faked.

Comment: the scenario is like when i click a sprite image on canvas and there's something wrong, i will show an error as a modal. and that's the point where the issue on onInputDown goes. so im not capturing a dom event. it's simply on the phaser input event I rely on. sorry for bad english sir. thanks

Comment: But you can easily trigger a modal window to appear from an onInputDown event. It's just JavaScript - put the modal opening code into the callback.

Comment: but after that it seems that the canvas lose the focus. because after closing the popup, you click once on canvas and it does not trigger the listener. then if you click second time it can. like the issue i put on the link above about alert();. thanks.

Comment: Of course, the focus will revert to the DOM object you displayed. But that doesn't mean you can't set it back to the canvas again when you close it.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, you can do `game.canvas.focus()` after you close your modal to set the focus back to the game again.

Comment: finally :D thats what im looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? this.input.onDown.add(obj.method,obj);